# Was ist der Ursprung von "marktgerechte Demokratie" oder "marktkonforme Demokratie"?

Tags: etymology

In den letzten Jahren verbreitete sich der Begriff der "marktgerechten Demokratie" oder "marktkonformen Demokratie". Was ist der Ursprung des Begriffs, also wer hat ihn in welchem Zusammenhang geprägt? Oder entstand das einfach spontan?

Comment: Habe ich weder je gehört noch gelesen, und kommt mir auch nicht wie eine sinnvolle Kombnation vor. *Marktgerecht* heißt üblicherweise, dass etwas aufgrund seiner Eigenschaften und seines Preises einen Markt hat, also gut verkäuflich ist.

Comment: Gemeint ist wahrscheinlich "marktkonforme Demokratie", siehe dazu beispielsweise [diesen Artikel in der FAZ](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/harte-bretter/marktkonforme-demokratie-oder-demokratiekonformer-markt-11712359.html).

Comment: @Uwe: Korrekt, das meinte ich, wo ich es gerade sah war es marktgerecht. Ich erweitere mal die frage entsprechend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der Ausdruck geht auf Angela Merkel zurück. Auf der Pressekonferenz anlässlich des Besuchs des portugiesischen Ministerpräsidenten Pedro Passos Coelho sagte sie am 1. September 2011:

> Frage: Frau Bundeskanzlerin, fürchten sie um die Schlagkraft des [EFSF](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europ%C3%A4ische_Finanzstabilisierungsfazilit%C3%A4t), wenn der Bundestag und alle anderen nationalen Parlamente in Europa demnächst bei allen wichtigen Entscheidungen vorab mitbestimmen wollen?
>
> BK’in Merkel: Wir leben ja in einer Demokratie und sind auch froh darüber. Das ist eine parlamentarische Demokratie. Deshalb ist das Budgetrecht ein Kernrecht des Parlaments. Insofern werden wir Wege finden, die parlamentarische Mitbestimmung so zu gestalten, dass sie trotzdem auch marktkonform ist, also dass sich auf den Märkten die entsprechenden Signale ergeben. <sup>[Quelle](http://www.bundesregierung.de/ContentArchiv/DE/Archiv17/Mitschrift/Pressekonferenzen/2011/09/2011-09-01-merkel-coelho.html), mit Dank an @Uwe und @chirlu, die mich auf die richtige Spur brachten und die Tomaten von den Augen nahmen</sup>

In der öffentlichen Debatte scheint im Anschluss zum Teil "marktkonform" durch "marktgerecht" ersetzt worden zu sein, und aus der "parlamentarischen Mitbestimmung", auf das sich das Adjektiv bezog, wurde gleich die ganze Demokratie. Viele Google-Treffer zu "marktgerechte Demokratie" nennen Angela Merkel als Urheberin. Die ältesten Treffer, die ich dafür finden konnte, sind Nutzerkommentare auf http://www.bei-abriss-aufstand.de/2011/09/29/sozietat-mann-muller-fordert-ablosung-der-sta-stuttgart/ und http://diepresse.com/home/wirtschaft/international/717546/Schattenbanken_Das-naechste-Pyramidenspiel vom 30.09. und 19.12. 2011, also in einer plausiblen zeitlichen Beziehung zu jener Pressekonferenz. Ende 2011 taucht die verfälschte Formulierung in [diesem Jahresrückblick eines SPD-Gemeindeverbands](http://www.spd-gemeindeverband-bza.de/index.php?mod=content&page_id=3124&s=34526) auf, Anfang 2013 [behauptet dann Petra Pau](http://linksfraktion.de/reden/neujahrsempfang-landtagsfraktion-linke-sachsen-anhalt-22-01-2013/) und damit eine Vizepräsidentin des Bundestags "Bundeskanzlerin Angela Merkel wirbt für eine marktgerechte Demokratie."

Comment: Interessant, das kommt direkt von Merkel? Hört sich eher wie ein Kommentar auf die Politik an.

Comment: @Mnementh, Matthias: Habt ihr den von Uwe verlinkten FAZ-Artikel gelesen? Er enthält das exakte Zitat. (Spoiler: Sowohl _marktkonform_ als auch _Demokratie_ kommen darin vor, die Kombination aber nicht.)

Comment: @chirlu Hätte ich wohl tun sollen, aber so, wie Uwe ihn "angeteasert" hat, hielt ich den Link für eine Ablenkung. Danke für den Tip.

Comment: Danke! Interessant dass das aus diesem Zitat dann im Endeffekt so zusammenkondensiert wurde.